# Getting the results of a rigid body simulation via Python

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to run a physics simulation with a single rigid body (cylinder) launched randomly on a flat surface. I want to know using python on which side (or edge) did the cylinder land. The ultimate goal is to launch the cylinder a lot of times to get statistical results for different values of the ratio diameter/height.

I'm using blender render, I achieve the random launch by setting random locations and rotations on frames 1 and 5 with the "animated" box checked, then this box is automatically unchecked with a *keyframe*.
I'm then using `bpy.ops.rigidbody.bake_to_keyframes` to compute the result of the simulation at frame 199 (I consider the motion to be over), and I read the locations and rotations.
I found that this method doesn't work, because a step is missing : "Apply transformation". I found that before this button is pressed, the locations and rotations are inaccurate. I tried automating this by writing `bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()` in my script but it doesn't seem to have any impact.
This could be because blender stops some calculations while a script is running.

Please note that I started using blender for this project a few days ago, so I'm a beginner, and English is not my first language I might make mistakes.

Note that I'm running blender 2.79.

Here is the code :

```
import bpy
import random

bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 1
obj=bpy.context.object
#setting random initial position and rotation on frame 1
obj.location[0]=float(random.randint(-50,50))/800
obj.location[1]=float(random.randint(-50,50))/800
obj.location[2]=11.0+float(random.randint(-20,20))/100
obj.rotation_euler[0]=float(random.randint(-80,80))/10
obj.rotation_euler[1]=float(random.randint(-80,80))/10
obj.rotation_euler[2]=float(random.randint(-80,80))/10
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1.0, index=0)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1.0, index=1)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1.0, index=2)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=1.0, index=0)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=1.0, index=1)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=1.0, index=2)

#setting random initial position and rotation on frame 5
obj.location[0] =float(random.randint(-20,20))/800
obj.location[1]=float(random.randint(-20,20))/800
obj.location[2]=11.90+float(random.randint(-20,20))/100
obj.rotation_euler[0]=float(random.randint(-200,200))/10
obj.rotation_euler[1]=float(random.randint(-200,200))/10
obj.rotation_euler[2]=float(random.randint(-200,200))/10
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=5.0, index=0)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=5.0, index=1)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=5.0, index=2)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=5.0, index=0)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=5.0, index=1)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=5.0, index=2)

bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 199
bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()
bpy.ops.rigidbody.bake_to_keyframes(frame_start=199, frame_end=199)
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
#storing rotations and height value
bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()
X,Y,Z=bpy.data.objects["Cylinder"].rotation_euler
height=bpy.data.objects["Cylinder"].location[2]

#some code
```

It is really that last part of the code that bothers me, as the height value is not consistent with the actual position on the cylinder.
If anyone knows any way around this problem, or another way to solve it, please help me. The rest is just a matter of looping everything and graphing, which I should know.

Thank you everyone

UPDATE : Further investigation reveals that the value I get for the z-coordinate (or any other) corresponds to the LAST run of the script, despite the use of `bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()`. After discovering this, I tried to loop the code and deduce the result of a simulation from the next one, but what I ended up with was the z-coordinates of the fifth frame of the previous simulation. In the end I sense that the position updates only when the script is ended and exited, which kind of relies to my earlier statement "This could be because blender stops some calculations while a script is running.". However, I am not able to describe this phenomenon more accurately as I didn't find useful information about it and as a beginner I can not look at the source code to understand it.
I would be glad if someone could help me understand this.